# New modules not imported

Tags: python, python-import, macos-monterey

After updating macOs to Monterey, every new modules I install with pip won’t be imported in my Python programs. My sis.path are good and all the packages I need are in the site-packages. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: I don't have any MacOS specific advice to give, but I'd just make sure that you're running your program (where you try to do the `import`) with the same interpreter you've installed them for. Having multiple versions of Python installed is common, and messy, on many systems. There's even [an XKCD comic about it](https://xkcd.com/1987/).

Comment: @Blckknght Actually I run the exactly same program which worked before I updated macOS so the whole installation is absolutely the same.

Comment: Remember that MacOS ships with both Python 2 and Python 3.  Make absolutely sure your `pip` is installing in the same version you're running.  This is why people often suggest `python -m pip install xxxx`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your python environment.

try `which pip3` or `which python3` to check locate your active python directory.

You can have different python versions installed in macOS which often leads to this issue.

Or maybe you are using virtual environments which creates isolated site-packages. If this is intended, then you should run your script within this environment to use the packages that you've installed.

Comment: which pip3 returns : /usr/local/bin/pip3

Comment: And which python3 returns : /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: but which python returns /usr/bin/python. And I have no virtual environment

Comment: then make sure you install package with `pip3` command and run your script with `python3 <your .py file>`. Because `python` and `python3` are different.

Comment: Oh and that is, if you are using python3 ofcourse. If you intend to use python2 then do so with `pip` & `python` commands.

Comment: You made my day ! It works if I run within the terminal python3 <myfile.py> but why doesn't it work with the vs code run button ?

Comment: that is probably because, the default python interpreter in your vscode is set to `python` which is python2. Your current interpreter is shown below left in vscode. You can click it to change. If problem is solve plz upvote & accept answer. thanks.